# Redshift COPY or snapshots?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-athena

i'm looking at using AWS Redshift to let users submit queries against the old archived data which isn't available in my web page.

the total data i'm dealing with across all my users is a couple of terabytes. the data is already in an s3 bucket, split up into files by week. most requests won't deal with more than a few files totaling 100GB.

to keep costs down should i use snapshots and delete our cluster when not in use or should i have a smaller cluster which doesn't hold all of the data and only COPY data from S3 into a temporary table when running a query?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just doing occasional queries where cost is more important than speed, you could consider using [Amazon Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/athena/), which can query data stored in Amazon S3. (Only in some AWS regions at the moment.) You are only charged for the amount of data read from disk.

To gain an appreciation for making Athena even better value, see: [Analyzing Data in S3 using Amazon Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyzing-data-in-s3-using-amazon-athena/)

[Amazon Redshift Spectrum](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-getting-started-using-spectrum.html) can perform a similar job to Athena but requires an Amazon Redshift cluster to be running.

All other choices are really a trade-off between cost and access to your data. You could start by taking a **snapshot** of your Amazon Redshift database and then **turning it off at night and on the weekends**. Then, have a script that can restore it automatically for queries. **Use fewer nodes** to reduce costs -- this will make queries slower, but that doesn't seem to be an issue for you.